# Monthly calendar view with event bars spanning days proportionate to time-of-day

Tags: html, calendar, scheduling

I need a calendar component (pref. JavaScript-based, possibly using jQuery) that will show me the month view. On this month view I can have multiple appointments that span multiple days as you can see by the colored bars.

[image: Photograph of calendar]

What is important is that the bars should start and end in the middle of a day. Also one should be able to add description to the bars

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://fullcalendar.io/ it uses javascript, jquery and moment.js and can handle all your requirements.